# Pass data from the observer to the phtml/block to display the data on the page in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I would like to know if the following is possible and if so how should something like this be achieved:
I have an observer which listens to an even when a product is clicked. I know that I can get the product ID, Name etc within this observer. I used Mage::log to write the clicked product's ID and Name to the system log file just to see if it's working. What I want to do now is retrieve the data from the observer and use the data like outside this observer file.

**Observer.php**

```
public function getProductData($observer) {

    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $pId = $product->getId();
    $pName = $product->getName();

    Mage::log($pId);
    Mage::log($pName);

}
```

How can I pass the data like $pId and $pName to the phtml file or block file and then display it on my page?

Comment: Can you please mention name of the event. ?

Comment: The event is called "catalog_controller_product_view"

Comment: Can you please also share the Layout entry. I mean what is block name and template file.